# How to: The ~ operator?

Tags: javascript

I can't google the ~ operator to find out more about it. Can someone please explain to me in simple words what it is for and how to use it?

Comment: a good place to learn more about it is [Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleTechTalks?) then search for javascript

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is a [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators).

Most common use I've seen is a **double bitwise NOT**, for removing the decimal part of a number, e.g:

```
var a = 1.2;
~~a; // 1
```

Why not use `Math.floor`? The trivial reason is that it is faster and uses fewer bytes. The more important reason depends on how you want to treat negative numbers. Consider:

```
var a = -1.2;
Math.floor(a); // -2
~~a; // -1
```

So, use `Math.floor` for **rounding down**, use `~~` for **chopping off** <sup>(not a technical term)</sup>.

Comment: Pretty obvious, but for anyone interested, (I think) the technical term for "chopping off" would be "truncating." Using the double bitwise not for this purpose is probably faster and use less memory than `Math.floor`, but the resulting number would still use the same amount of memory since JavaScript makes no distinction between integers, floats, etc. for numerical values.

Answer (score 5):

One usage of the ~ (Tilde) I have seen was getting boolean for .indexOf().

You could use: `if(~myArray.indexOf('abc')){ };`

Instead of this: `if(myArray.indexOf('abc') > -1){ };`

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmuv1hwt/1/)

---

Additional Info: [The Great Mystery of the Tilde(~)](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/)

Search Engine that allows special characters: [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a tilde and it is the bitwise NOT operator.

Answer (score 1):

~ is a bitwise NOT operator. It will invert the bits that make up the value of the stored variable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_NOT_.22.7E.22_.2F_one.27s_complement_.28unary.29