# ~ in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: The ~ operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260475/how-to-the-operator)

What's the ~ operator does in javascript?

input

```
alert(~1)
```

output is

```
-2
```

input

```
~function () {}()
```

output is

```
-1
```

I never heard about ~ operator in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the bitwise **not** operator that inverts the value of every bit in the integer.  In binary a signed integer has the following representation:

```
00000001 = 1
11111110 = -2
```

See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

`Bitwise NOT    ~ a Inverts the bits of its operand.`

I guess its fairly odd that a function returns -1, but what would you expect anyway.

Comment: The function call returns `undefined`. `undefined` is converted to `0` and `~0` is `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

> The bitwise NOT operator (~) will take its operand, convert it to a
>   32-bit integer, and will invert each bit so that each 0 becomes a 1
>   and vice versa.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/