# What does `!!~` mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators, mongoose, bitwise-operators, comparison-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does tilde (~) preceding jQuery object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316612/what-does-tilde-preceding-jquery-object-do)

I found a strange `!!~` in the code when reading: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L678

```
Document.prototype.isModified = function (path) {
  return !!~this.modifiedPaths.indexOf(path);
};
```

I have read that [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) and [How to: The ~ operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260475/how-to-the-operator); why did the author use `!!~` here?

I tried:

```
!!~1  // -> true
!!~0  // -> true
!!~-1 // -> false
!!~-2 // -> true
```

It seems that it only be `false` when the number is `-1`. Is it right? Why not just check the number is not `-1` or `>=0`?