# What does -~ before .indexOf() mean?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I am looking at SocketIO source code and it has this statement:

```
if (-~manager.get('blacklist').indexOf(packet.name)) {
```

What does `-~` shorthand mean here?

Comment: It's not a "shorthand", it's two operators in a row (`-` and `~`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is appears to be a trick for:

```
if(manager.get('blacklist').indexOf(packet.name) !== -1)
```

As mentioned by others `~` is bitwise negation which will flip the binary digits. `00000001` becomes `11111110` for example, or in hexidecimal, `0x01` becomes `0xFE`.

`-1` as a signed int 32 which is what all bitwise operators return (other than `>>>` which returns a unsigned int 32) is represented in hex as `0xFFFFFFFF`. `~(-1)` flips the bits to result in `0x00000000` which is `0`.

The minus simply numerically negates the number. As zzzBov mentioned, in this case it does nothing.

```
-~(-1) === 0
```

And

```
~(-1) === 0
```

The code could be changed to:

```
if(~manager.get('blacklist').indexOf(packet.name))
```

But, in my opinion, characters aren't at such a premium so the longer version, which is arguably a bit more readable, would be better, or implementing a contains method would be even better, this version is best left to a JavaScript compiler or compressor to perform this optimization.

Answer (score 4):

Bitwise inversion.

```
~0 == 0xFFFFFFFF == -1
~1 == 0xFFFFFFFE
```

Minus is arithmetic inversion. So result is 0 if indexOf failed (return -1)

Answer (score 3):

The two operators are not a shorthand form of anything. `~` is bitwise negation, and `-` is standard negation.

[`~foo.indexOf(bar)` is a common shorthand for `foo.contains(bar)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582286/what-does-mean-in-javascript/10584043#10584043). Because the result is used in an `if` statement, the `-` sign immediately after is completely useless and does nothing of consequence.

`-~` together is a means to add `1` to a number. It's generally not useful, and would be better expressed as `+ 1`, [unless you're competing in a code golf where you're not allowed to use the digit `1`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/hello-world-0-0/1538#1538)